# Why do most piyutim and zemirot have an acrostic with the author's name?

Tags: song-poetry, shabbat-songs

Many of the Shabbat zemirot contain an acrostic of the (part of the) author's name, usually using a letter of his name at the start of each verse. For example, *Y-ah Ribon* has the name *Yisra'el*; *Yom Ze Leyisra'el* is *Yitzhak*; *Akdamut* has a long acrsotic at it's end, part of which spells *Me'ir b'Rebbi Yitzhak*.

I'm unaware if this technique was common in general (non-Jewish) poetic writing during that era. Is this unique or more frequently done in Jewish poetry? Why was this done? Was there a specific reason for embedding the author's name in this fashion, rather than just, say, putting a "signature" or some other ID so people will know who composed the piyut / zemer?

Comment: Signing one's name in an acrostic poem was commonly done in non-Jewish poetry from much earlier than the period in question. See: [The Cambridge Ancint History III part 2 The Assyrian and Babylonian Empires and Other States of the Near East, from the Eighth to the Sixth Centuries B.C., p. 299](https://books.google.com/books?id=OGBGauNBK8kC&pg=PA299&lpg=PA299&dq=signing+name+in+acrostic+poem+history&source=bl&ots=wnr5Tq5WMm&sig=KvolEKbYxvLPDmWc0-1VkuLTpbI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHzaGS67PRAhWKy4MKHfPAAEYQ6AEIUDAN#v=onepage&q=signing%20name%20in%20acrostic%20poem%20history&f=false).

Comment: Acrostics were also used in [medieval poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrostic#Overview) to record the poet's name. The Middle High German poet Rudolf von Ems (13th cent.) for example opens all his great works with an acrostic of his name.

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: Has it occurred to you that maybe they did this so that you would know who wrote the zemer? I think you're making this more hard than it actually is.

Comment: @EzraHoerster The OP already mentioned that possibility: `rather than just, say, putting a "signature" or some other ID so people will know who composed the piyut / zemer`

Comment: @DoubleAA Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: @DanF It's asking to compare Jewish and non-Jewish practices.

Comment: Furthermore, the Jewish practice might be considered more Jews than Judaism.

Comment: Yom Zeh L'yisrael actually spells out Yitzchak Luria Chazak (יצחק לוריא חזק); the 9th verse has the ח and the optional 10th verse has the זק.  I think Ashkenazic siddurim might omit some verses; the Koren-Sacks, for example, only has verses 1, 2, 3, 4, 9.

Comment: I always thought the reason was to remember the order of the verses. It was for those times when sufficient zemiros books or siddurim were not available.

Comment: @MauroBraunstein Everything after ל is a later addition. The first part of the song predates the Ari (accd to http://old.piyut.org.il/textual/381.html).